# perl: assign interval to number with hash keys, increment counter if number is in interval

Tags: perl, hash, compare, key

I have several pairs of numbers and want to check whether the first one falls into a given interval. If so, I want to increment one of two counters for that interval, depending on whether the second number of the pair is higher or lower than the first.

The intervals are simple and look like 1-10,11-20,21-30 etc. The pairs of numbers look like (5,15),(24,13) etc. But I have several thousand of each. The exact format of input does not matter so much.

The desired outcome looks like this

```
1-10: higher=1, lower=0
11-20: higher=0,lower=0
21-30: higher=0,lower=1
```

My idea was to create a hash with the interval start as key and store the two counters in the value.

```
for(my $i = $start;$i<=$end;$i = ($i+$intervalsize)){
    my $counter1 = 0;
    my $counter2 = 0;
    @{$hash{$i}} = ($counter1,$counter2);
```

but now I don't know how to compare the numbers with the keys and how to address the counters.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Its not entirely clear on what you are expecting.  Could you provide some input and expected output?

Comment: ok I see I forgot to make clear, that I have thousands of intervals and even more pairs of numbers, sorry!  so I wanted to avoid to go through each pair and interval in nested for loops :(

Comment: also, the format of input does not matter so much

Answer (score 0):

If the counters are to be kept for each interval we can record them in a data structure of choice. For example, store counters for each interval in a hash with the key being the interval index and low-high counters being in a two-element refarray as its value.

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

my @intervals = ( [1,10], [11,20], [21,30] );
my @pairs     = ( [5,15], [24, 13] );

my %counter = map { $_ => [0,0] } (0..$#intervals);  # initialize

foreach my $i (0..$#intervals) 
{
    foreach my $pair (@pairs)
    {   
        my ($beg, $end) = @{$intervals[$i]};
        my ($pl, $pr)   = @$pair;

        if ($pl >= $beg and $pl <= $end) 
        {   
            if ($pr > $pl) { ++$counter{$i}[1] }   
            else           { ++$counter{$i}[0] }   
        }   
    }   
}

print "$_ => @{$counter{$_}}\n" for sort keys %counter;
```

This is still rudimentary, in order to be easier to adjust. For one thing, since the hash uses the index of `@intervals` array it may well be an array (with arrayrefs) itself.  Another possibility is to use a hash with keys like `low` and `high` for counters instead of a two-element array.

---

In order to use start of interval as a key

```
my %counter = map { $_->[0] => [0,0] } @intervals;  # initialize

for my $inter (@intervals) {
    for my $pair (@pairs) {
        my ($beg, $end) = @$inter;
        my ($pl, $pr)   = @$pair;

        if ($pl >= $beg and $pr <= $end) 
        {   
            if ($pr > $pl) { ++$counter{$beg}[1] }
            else           { ++$counter{$end}[0] }
        }
    }
}
printf("%3d => @{$counter{$_}}\n", $_) for sort keys %counter;
```

Comment: OP is probably preprocessing data for a statistical test.

Comment: From OP's desired output, it seems that OP wants high and low to be recorded separately for all intervals. A dirty way would be using `$inter->[2]` as high and 3 as low - a better way may be defining `@records` and loop with `$i` so can alter the values `$records->[$i]->[0]` for high.

Comment: @SunnyPun  Thank you for the comment -- yes, it looked like that, but I just wasn't sure.  Added to the answer.

Comment: @Jule I added a version to keep counters for each interval.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw( first_index );

sub interval_to_key { sprintf '(%d,%d)', @{ $_[0] } }

my @intervals = (
    [  1, 10 ],
    [ 11, 20 ],
    [ 21, 30 ],
);

my @upper_bounds = map $_->[0], @intervals;

my @pairs = (
    [  5, 15 ],
    [ 24, 13 ],
);

my @keys = qw( ascending descending );

my %counts;

for my $interval ( @intervals ) {
    @{ $counts{ interval_to_key($interval) } }{ @keys } = (0) x @keys;
}

for my $pair ( @pairs ) {
    my $is_ascending = ($pair->[0] <= $pair->[1]);

    my $i = first_index { $pair->[0] <= $_ } @upper_bounds;

    ++ $counts{ interval_to_key( $intervals[$i]) }{ $keys[1 - $is_ascending] };
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%counts;
```